# and/or statement only prints out 1 output but I need all of them, python

Tags: python

```
with open(path_to_file, mode='r') as handle:

    out = open("", 'w')
    for line in handle:
        if not "|CA" and "|CO" and "|CT" in line:
                out.write(line)
out.close()
```

When I run it, it only prints out the information that is associated to CT. I want to see the information for CA, CO and CT.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). For debugging help, you need to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including complete but minimal code and expected behaviour. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70384330/edit). For more tips, see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `if not "|CA" and "|CO" and "|CT" in line:` is not doing what you think

Comment: `in` doesn't distribute across `and`. it should be `if x not in line and y not in line and z not in line:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That expression is interpreted as:

```
    if (not "|CA") and ("|CO") and ("|CT" in line):
```

`not "|CA"` will never be true, so the `if` statement should never be taken.  If you want lines where ANY of those are present, then you want:

```
    if "|CA" in line or "|CO" in line or "|CT" in line:
```

Comment: Better yet, `if any(f'|{x}' in line for x in ["CA", "CO", "CT"])`:

Comment: I debated that.  In my humble opinion, that is less efficient and doesn't read as clearly.  Honestly, this is one case where I'd be tempted to use a regular expression.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this

```py
import re

path = 'hej.txt'

open('out.file', 'w').writelines(
    x for x in open(path) 
    if not re.search(r'\|C[AOT]', x)
)
```